# Function for cross table calculation

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create function that will automatically put my results in a data frame. I have a data_frame with one nominal variable and few logical variables:

```
categ_var      var_log1    var_log2   var_log3     var_log4
cat1           TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE
cat2           FALSE       TRUE       NA           TRUE
cat2           FALSE       NA         FALSE        FALSE
cat4           TRUE        FALSE      TRUE         FALSE
cat1           NA          NA         TRUE         FALSE
cat3           TRUE        FALSE      FALSE        FALSE
cat3           TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE
cat1           FALSE       TRUE       NA           TRUE
cat3           FALSE       NA         FALSE        FALSE
cat5           TRUE        FALSE      TRUE         FALSE
cat6           NA          NA         TRUE         FALSE
cat7           TRUE        FALSE      FALSE        FALSE
```

And after using fuction:

```
as.data.frame(example %>% filter(var_log1 == TRUE) %>% pull(categ_var) %>% table(useNA = 'always'))
```

I receive this as a result:

```
     . Freq
1 cat1    1
2 cat2    0
3 cat3    2
4 cat4    1
5 cat5    1
6 cat6    0
7 cat7    1
8 <NA>    0
```

Now, I would love to do two things:
a) to have a column name that equals variable name that I'm using (instead of 'Freq'),
b) to create a function that uses all of these logical variables from a source data frame and puts it into one data frame with their appropriate column names.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
            var_log1 var_log2 var_log3
1   cat1        1       2        2
2   cat2        0       1        1
3   cat3        2       1        1
4   cat4        1       0        0
5   cat5        1       0        0
6   cat6        0       0        0
7   cat7        1       0        0
8   NA          0       0        0
```

Comment: Any sample desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will always have `0` in the `NA`-row, as you filter by `TRUE` only. Using the fact, that `TRUE` is `1` in a `sum` you can summarize the data in the following way:

```
library(dplyr)

example %>% 
  group_by(categ_var) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum, na.rm = T)

# A tibble: 7 x 5
#   categ_var var_log1 var_log2 var_log3 var_log4
#      <fctr>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
# 1      cat1        1        2        1        2
# 2      cat2        0        1        0        1
# 3      cat3        2        1        0        1
# 4      cat4        1        0        1        0
# 5      cat5        1        0        1        0
# 6      cat6        0        0        1        0
# 7      cat7        1        0        0        0
```

Comment: You can do that, by using `rbind` and add the `NA` row to the data (i.e. `rbind(example, c(NA, rep(0, ncol(example) - 1))`.
`NA` is not really a `categ_var`, it only counts the number of `NA`s in your filtered data, which will always be `0` as you only take the `TRUE` values.

Comment: I guess i didn't explain myself well. I mean when there will be no category from categ_var, so it's NA as a category, but in the same time it can be 'TRUE' for the other variables. Like var_log1 can be TRUE without a category, rite?

Comment: Maybe you can update you question with example data that fits more your scenario? In you data you always have a `categ_var` and I don't see how `var_log1` can be `TRUE` without a category...
If there is a `NA` in you `categ_var` this will be picked up by `group_by`

Comment: Yeah thats true, I do always have categ_var. My mistake. There should be an NA somewhere. thank you :)